# Erro ao chamar um método secundário via CALLBACK: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome_do_metodo_secundario' of undefined

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, ecmascript-6

Com JavaScript (ECMAScript-6), ao chamar um método via *callback*, caso esse método utilize um outro método ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome_do_metodo_secundario' of undefined

Se o método é chamado diretamente funciona perfeitamente. Porém se for chamado via *callback* não funciona. Se não tiver um método secundário, também funciona.

**Como fazer para chamar via *callback*, um método de uma classe, sendo que este método utiliza outros métodos?**

Abaixo um trecho de código reproduzindo o erro:

```js
class TestOne{
    metodoPrincipal(str_input){
        this.metodoSecundario(str_input);
    }
  
    metodoSecundario(parametro){
        alert("OK: " + parametro);
    }     
}

function chamaViaCallback(callback, msg){
  callback(msg);
}


var test_objeto = new TestOne(); // instancia o objeto

 // funciona chamando diretamente um método secundário
test_objeto.metodoPrincipal('Testando método secundário chamado diretamente!');

// funciona via callback chamando diretamente o método secundário
chamaViaCallback(test_objeto.metodoSecundario, 'método único chamado via callback!');

// não funciona via callback chamando método secundário
chamaViaCallback(test_objeto.metodoPrincipal, 'método secundário chamado via callback!');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema ocorre porque a função `metodoPrincipal` perde a referência do objeto.

Uma forma de resolver isto é passar o objeto através do [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
chamaViaCallback(test_objeto.metodoPrincipal.bind(test_objeto), 'Foo');
```

Uma outra alternativa com uma função de seta ([Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
chamaViaCallback( msg => test_objeto.metodoPrincipal(msg), 'Bar');
```

Se preferir chamar a função de seta sem argumentos e passar diretamente a mensagem:

```
chamaViaCallback( () => { test_objeto.metodoPrincipal('Baz'); } );
```

Exemplo:

```js
class TestOne{
    metodoPrincipal(str_input){
        this.metodoSecundario(str_input);
    }
  
    metodoSecundario(parametro){
        console.log("OK: " + parametro);
    }     
}

function chamaViaCallback(callback, msg){
  callback(msg);
}

var test_objeto = new TestOne(); // instancia o objeto

chamaViaCallback( test_objeto.metodoPrincipal.bind(test_objeto), 'Foo' );
chamaViaCallback( msg => test_objeto.metodoPrincipal(msg), 'Bar' );
chamaViaCallback( () => { test_objeto.metodoPrincipal('Baz'); } );
```

Comment: Obs: não precisa apenas da flecha de função para fazer a segunda alternativa, mas gostei da ideia de wrap com arrows

Comment: @stderr, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou certinho (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Quando você passa `test_objeto.metodoPrincipal` para o *callback* a função do objeto é chamada, porém ele não conseguirá chamar a função `metodoSecundario` pois você não passou o objeto, e sim apenas a função.

Logo, o objeto (a variável `this`) não é definido.

Uma solução é passar objeto e o nome da função (como uma *string*) como *callback*.

Exemplo, seguindo o seu código:

```
function chamaMetodoViaCallback(obj, method, msg){
    obj[method](msg);
}

chamaMetodoViaCallback(test_objeto, "metodoPrincipal", 'método secundário chamado via callback!');
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou certinho aqui. Porém, no meu caso, será mais viável passar como objeto mesmo. A resposta do stderr se adequou melhor à minha situação. (+1 para vc)

Answer (score 2):

> Como fazer para chamar via callback, um método de uma classe, sendo que este método utiliza outros métodos?

Se você pretende referenciar `test_objeto.metodoPrincipal` sem passar `test_objeto` para `chamaViaCallback`, use o método [`Function#bind(instância, argumentos)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
test_objeto.metodoPrincipal.bind(test_objeto)
```

`Function#bind` retorna a mesma função, coberta por instância e argumentos pré-definidos.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou certo aqui. (+1 para você.)